# Alternative solution to CAPTCHA

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

Can I use a minimum time between two posts from the same person instead of using a captcha? if so can anyone give me an example ?

Comment: What do you mean by "posts"? Are you writing a forum software?

Comment: @zespri he means: "avoid users from sending two page postbacks in a short time". You you click a button twice it will make two postbacks, sometimes it was caused by an accident of double clicking a button. Javascript to disable the button is one option, but I guess he wants to do server-side.

Comment: @zespri a simple example: a user wants to post in his blog, he fills the post and click the button. The site is running slow, so he clicks again, and again, and again, now it saved! He checks his blog and "damnit there are 4 same posts"

Comment: @BrunoLM: Never heard of any one using captcha to prevent double posts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [NoBot](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/NoBot/NoBot.aspx) control in asp.net ajax control toolkit

Comment: Interestingly I was not able to pass the test given on the sample page. I was rejected as being a bot every time. Using Firefox 4 in a pretty standard config (ie. No javascript or cookies disabled)

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, yes, this would be easy to do if you are storing the posts in a database with a time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

The question is "how important is it to you to avoid bots & spam". If it is not very important then you can remove captcha altogether. IMHO I don't think "minimum time" is a good measure of "this is not a bot..."

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ask a question to user like a trivial cultural question and then check the answer. Looking about the time works only for avoid intense spam, but it's not helping the fact than bot shouldn't be able to post anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement something like that - no captchas but avoid massive form spam - with all pros and cons.
In a db we store a list of requests with timestamp, ip address, page key,  userid and so on, we compare if a request follows another request within a give timeframe and if this happens several times we automatically inform the it admins. we also tested a script to block the origin ip address on the firewalls and other things. dont know what is currently activated. The db is cleaned from old entries very often.

So yes you can - either store in memory or use a db to store the information you need to identify the requests/posts.